# Append values to one dataframe based on their frequency in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, df1 is the product of a groupby, or `df.groupby('keyword')`:

```
df1

keyword     string

   A        "This is a test string for the example" 
            "This is also a test string based on the other string"
            "This string is a test string based on the other strings"
   B        "You can probably guess that this is also a test string"
            "Yet again, another test string"
            "This is also a test"
```

and df2

which is an empty dataframe, now I also I have a list of specific values:

```
keyword_list = ['string', 'test']
```

Basically I would like to count the frequency of each word that is in `keyword_list` and within `df1` and the word that appears the most append that word to a a specific column in the new dataframe based on the keyword in df1, so df2's `'A'` gets assigned the highest occurring value in df1's `string` column.

So ideally, since `'string'` is the highest occuring value in df1's `A` keyword column it gets assigned `string` and so on.

```
df2

keyword    High_freq_word

   A         "string"
   B         "test"
```

Let me know if you need some clarification or it makes sense!

UPDATE:

@anky_91 provided some awesome code however the output is a little awkward

```
df['matches'] = df.description.str.findall('|'.join(keyword_list))

    df.groupby(odf.Type.ffill()).matches.apply(lambda x: ''.join(mode(list(chain.from_iterable(x)))[0]))
```

gets you

df1

```
keyword     string                                                     

   A        "This is a test string for the example" 
            "This is also a test string based on the other string"
            "This string is a test string based on the other strings"
   B        "You can probably guess that this is also a test string"
            "Yet again, another test string"
            "This is also a test"
```

However it adds a new column:

```
matches

['string','test']
['test', 'string','string]
[etc...]
```

I can figure out a way to convert it numerically and then assign that value to the column, but the bigger issue is appending this new column to the the new dataframe.

Since it is a groupby there are several duplicate values, I'm trying to find a pythonic way of mapping the "most frequent word" to just the keyword itself instead of the entire mode based on the list of key words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you can do something like:

```
from itertools import chain
from scipy.stats import mode
```

---

```
keyword_list = ['string', 'test']
df['matches']=df.string.str.findall('|'.join(keyword_list)) #find all matches
df.groupby(df.keyword.ffill()).matches.apply(lambda x: ''.join(mode(list(chain.from_iterable(x)))[0]))
```

---

```
keyword
A    string
B      test
Name: matches, dtype: object
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, this works right now I just need to append it to the new dataframe as opposed to just creating a new column in the old one!

Comment: @SebastianGoslin you can call `reset_index()` to the output and assign it to a new dataframe. :)

Comment: Was just about to ask, since I just got a key error!

Comment: Ok now I'm running into this issue when I call `reset_index()` `ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long'`

Comment: @SebastianGoslin okay, not sure why, works fine on the test data? may be check this: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20986

Comment: looks like a pandas issue, Im gonna try appending the values to a dictionary then mapping it to the new dataframe, hopefully that'll work