# appending the most common element in a CELL to a column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is related to a question I asked earlier, I'm posting this new one as I think its sufficiently [unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56346189/append-values-to-one-dataframe-based-on-their-frequency-in-another-dataframe) and persistently difficult. I have a data frame of the form:

```
keyword       string                 match

A             "Varied String..."     ['string','string','test','string']
              "Varied String..."     ['string','string']
              "Varied String..."     ['test']
B             "Varied String..."     ['string,'string','test']
```

Which was created via this code (which was written by @anky_91):

```
df1.groupby(df2.Type.ffill()).matches.apply(lambda x: ''.join(mode(list(chain.from_iterable(x)))[0]))
```

My issue at this point, this creates a new column matches which is perfectly normal, however while I do want the mode, I only want the most frequent unique value. So instead of the `match` column being populated with a list mode, I'm trying to get it to just be the most frequent value of the mode so:

```
 keyword           string               match

    A             "Varied String..."    'string'
    B             "Varied String..."    'string'
```

I tried doing this:

`df = freq_df['matches'].agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])`

Which returns, the same thing unchanged. I then try,

`df['matches'].value_counts()`

Which returns inaccurate counts so I'm not sure whats going on with that.

Let me know if this is clear or not!

Comment: What is df1 and df2?

Comment: I think you want to use apply instead of agg

Comment: @Will df1 is the dataframe without the `matches` column and df2 is the `matches` column added to it, the `matches` column was derived from the `string` column in df1 where each row is sentence containing specific keywords (in this case `"string","test"`), does that help?

Comment: @iamchoosinganame I tried that but I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'value_counts'`

Comment: It's because the value is a list not a series. You can convert it to a series. ```df = freq_df['matches'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).value_counts().index[0])```

Comment: @iamchoosinganame It remains unchanged :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using *Series.str.findall()* to retrieve matches into lists, you can use [Series.str.extractall()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to retrieve each matched word onto its own row which could make your task easier (below using your sample data in the previous post and removed the double quotes from the *string* column).

```
# list of keywords
keyword_list=['string', 'test'] 

# regex pettern to retrieve only words matched from keywork_list
ptn = r'\b(' + '|'.join(keyword_list) + r')\b'

# get the list of matched words (assume `keyword` is already on index), if not, use the following
# s = df.set_index('keyword').string.str.extractall(ptn).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)[0]
s = df.string.str.extractall(ptn).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)[0]
print(s)
#keyword
#A      test
#A    string
#A      test
#A    string
#A    string
#A    string
#A      test
#A    string
#B      test
#B    string
#B      test
#B    string
#B      test
#Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Next you can retrieve the top item by value_counts() for each keyword

```
s.groupby('keyword').apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().nlargest(1))
#keyword   
#A        string    5
#B        test      3
#Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

or just keyword and string without the count:

```
s.groupby('keyword').apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax())
#keyword
#A    string
#B      test
#Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, just got back tot he office. This is perfect! The only thing I need to figure out at this point is how to assign the highest frequency string to a specific key word as of now its still displaying multiple frequencies per keyword

Comment: @SebastianGoslin, dont know if I understand you correctly, I think you are probably just missing one step to assign the result to a new dataframe: `df_new = s.groupby('keyword').apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax()).to_frame('most_freq_string')`

Comment: Ahhh that did it! If I could pick your brain for one more thing, its still returning multiple values for `A` since the dataframe is in long format so 'A' equals many different strings, is there a way to aggregate all the different values for `A` and assign it one? As of now it assigns the most frequent keyword in that row as opposed to all occurrences of `A`. Does that make sense please tell me if it doesn't!

Comment: Nevermind I found a way! `df.pivot_table(index='keyword', values='most_freq_string', aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(str(v) for v in x))`